# Using OrderedDict but in graph months out of order

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, ordereddictionary

I have a pivot_table being read into a bar plot using bokeh. The problem is that the months are plotted out of order, even though I am using OrderedDict. Here is a sample of the pivot_table

```
pivot_table.head(3)
Out[45]: 
Month                              1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  CompanyName                                                                     
Company1                           17  30  29  39  15  26  24  12  36  21  18   
Company2                           4  11  13  22  35  29  15  18  29  31  17   
Company3                          11   8  25  24   7  15  20   0  21  12  12   

Month                              12  
CompanyName                            
Company1     15  
Company2     14  
Company3     17
```

It is being read in using this code:

```
# get the months
Jan = pivot_table[1].astype(float).values
Feb = pivot_table[2].astype(float).values
Mar = pivot_table[3].astype(float).values
Apr = pivot_table[4].astype(float).values
May = pivot_table[5].astype(float).values
Jun = pivot_table[6].astype(float).values
Jul = pivot_table[7].astype(float).values
Aug = pivot_table[8].astype(float).values
Sep = pivot_table[9].astype(float).values
Oct = pivot_table[10].astype(float).values
Nov = pivot_table[11].astype(float).values
Dec = pivot_table[12].astype(float).values
# build a dict containing the grouped data
months = OrderedDict(Jan=Jan, Feb=Feb, Mar=Mar, Apr=Apr, May=May,Jun=Jun,Jul=Jul,Aug=Aug,Sep=Sep,Oct=Oct,Nov=Nov,Dec=Dec)


palette = brewer["PuBuGn"][8]

output_file("stacked_bar.html")
bar = Bar(months, Companies, title="Stacked bars", palette = palette, legend = "top_right", width = 1200, height=900, stacked=True)


show(bar)
```

The problem is that this is the output. Although beautiful, the months are out of order. I would like them to start at Jan on the bottom up through Dec.

[image]

Comment: the problem is that the parameters are collected by OrderedDict as a dictionary (kwargs), which is not ordered

Comment: @Pynchia How do I collect then by OrderedDict to be ordered?

Comment: store the months in a list then add them to the ordereddict one by one. I am trying to write an answer but I am in the middle of something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OrderedDict like this:

```
months = OrderedDict([('Jan', Jan), ('Feb', Feb), ('Mar', Mar)])
```

Or:

```
months = OrderedDict()
months['Jan'] = Jan
months['Feb'] = Feb
months['Mar'] = Mar
```

An OrderedDict is a dict that remembers the order that keys were first inserted. A dict (kwargs) doesn't have a specified order.

Comment: Thanks! This helped. I understand what happened now.

Comment: Is there a faster way to do this? Say if I want to pull a month of data and make an OrderedDict with each day of the month, without typing it out?

Comment: You can always use a loop to construct a tuple list first, and pass the list to OrderedDict.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the parameters are collected by OrderedDict as a dictionary (kwargs), which is not ordered.

Do this instead:

```
months = OrderedDict()
months['Jan'] = pivot_table[1].astype(float).values
months['Feb'] = pivot_table[2].astype(float).values
...
```

Comment: Is there a faster way to do this? Say if I want to pull a month of data and make an OrderedDict with each day of the month, without typing it out?

Comment: as in `for day in range(1,32): days[day]=pivot_table[day].astype(float).values` ?

Comment: You can play around with [date functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) and find out the best way for your context to use a date as an index/key (e.g. `date.toordinal`)

Comment: Yeah, I am thinking it would be good to have a stacked bar graph for four time frames, a year, a month, a week, and a day. An interesting challenge for a python beginner! :)

Answer (score 0):

For the months try this,

```
months = OrderedDict((
 ("Jan",Jan)
,("Feb",Feb)
,("Mar",Mar)
,("Apr",Apr)
,("May",May)
,("Jun",Jun)
,("Jul",Jul)
,("Aug",Aug)
,("Sep",Sep)
,("Oct",Oct)
,("Nov",Nov)
,("Dec",Dec)))
```